# How to print output on new line?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

```
case Constants.QUEUEESCALATION:
      {
        var body = '';
        angular.forEach(caseChangeRecord, function(change, key) {
          body += change.fieldName + Constants.QUEUEESCALATION_MSG + checkIfDate(change.originalValue) + Constants.TO + checkIfDate(change.newValue) + Constants.FULLSTOP + '\n';
        });
        return {
          objectType: Constants.TYPE_INFO,
          objectIcon: 'fa-list-ul',
          objectBody: body
        };
      }
```

After appending \n in last it will shown output on same line instated of new line.

**ACTUAL OUTPUT:**

assignedQueue has been changed from Q1 to Q48. assignedQueueDate has been changed from 06/27/2017 to 07/03/2017.

**REQUIRE OUTPUT:**

assignedQueue has been changed from Q1 to Q48.

assignedQueueDate has been changed from 06/27/2017 to 07/03/2017.

Comment: use double  `\n\n `

Comment: @RameshRajendran its not working...i also included </br> tag but same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide rows by `'\n'` token and wrap your `item.body` into `<pre>`:

```
    <div class="timeline-body">
      <pre>
{{item.body}}
      </pre>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a space before `\n`. It's working from my side.

```
body += change.fieldName + Constants.QUEUEESCALATION_MSG + checkIfDate
(change.originalValue) + Constants.TO + checkIfDate(change.newValue) + 
Constants.FULLSTOP + ' \n';
```

### Update :

and your html should be like using `innerHtml`

```
<div class="timeline-body" [innerHTML]="item.body"></div>
```

Comment: After tried provided solution still same output. No change in my side.

Comment: did you bind this in any html or what?

Comment: Yes i bind this on html (below binding code):

`<div class="timeline-body">
         {{item.body}}
 </div>`